# will_paginate problem with action and fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have added **action caching** to my **index** part and listing 9 records in a page

will_paginate dosent work, and renders same set of recors again and again.

and same issue with **fragment caching**

please suggest some solution for this..

thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this: [Rails action caching with querystring parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988658/rails-action-caching-with-querystring-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very basic Rails app, I would recommend using fragment caching as it's a much easier to use and maintain compared to action/page caching. If you decide to use fragment caching, you could add something like the following to your index template:

```
<% @models.each do |model| %>
  <% cache ["v1", model] do %>
    <%= render model %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will render the partial `_model.html.erb` and cache the result. For details about the cache mechanisms in Rails, I suggest reading [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

A more aggressive caching strategy would be to cache all the models on a single page. That could be done by setting the current page to an instance variable in the controller:

```
def index
  @page   = params[:page]
  @models = ...
end
```

Now in your template you can include the page in the composite cache key:

```
<% cache ["v1", cache_key_for(@models), @page] do %>
  <% @models.each do |model| %>
    <%= render model %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

`cache_key_for` is a helper that computes a cache key for a set of models. It could be defined as:

```
def cache_key_for(models)
  "#{models.count}-{models.map(&:updated_at).max.utc.to_s(:number)}"
end
```