# Rails Caching: Using sweepers for actions which require parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sweeper

I'm trying to use sweepers to handle my page refreshes. For refreshing index actions, etc everything works fine...but I can't seem to sweepers to interpret page parameters. If anyone can tell me what's wrong with the code below, I'd be very appreciative:

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  cache_sweeper :post_sweeper, :only => [:create, :update, :destroy]
  caches_page :index
  caches_page :show
  caches_action :edit, :new

  # This refreshes cache correctly
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
```

# This creates cache, but does not refresh it (ever). If I place the expire_page command directly into the action (instead of the sweeper), it works fine

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        flash[:notice] = t(:post_updated)
        format.html { redirect_to(@post) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The sweeper:

```
class PostSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Post

  def after_create(record)
    expire_cache_for_index(record)
  end

  def after_update(record)
    expire_cache_for_index(record)
    expire_cache_for_post(record)
    expire_cache_for_edit(record)
  end

  def after_destroy(record)
    expire_cache_for_index(record)
    expire_cache_for_post(record)
    expire_cache_for_edit(record)
  end

  private
  def expire_cache_for_index(record)
    expire_page :controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'
  end

  def expire_cache_for_post(record)
    expire_page :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => record.id
  end

  def expire_case_for_edit(record)
    expire_action :controller => 'posts', :action => 'edit', :id => record.id
  end

end
```

Comment: Your last private method in `PostSweeper` says `expire_case_for_edit`, but should probably say `expire_cache_for_edit`.

Comment: Google could be your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988658/rails-action-caching-with-querystring-parameters

Comment: dmarkow: Thanks for the catch - unfortunately the underlying problem still exists. Apneadiving: Cheers too - have tried it, but still no joy.

Comment: Think this should work, there is a typo in your method name for expiring the edit action, you have 'def expire_case_for_edit' not 'def expire_cache_for_edit', does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume you copy and pasted the code, then the typo is also in your code.  Since you did not get flagged with an error by Rails, we can then assume that the sweepers are not being called.  (i.e. the after_update is not being called).  I would add some logger messages in to verify that that really is the case.

Questions is about Post:

1. Is it a decedent of ActiveRecord::Base?
2. Do you have other callbacks that are returning false and thus stopping the chain?

The sweeper examples on the net consistently put the cache_sweeper line *after* the caches_xxx lines.  I'd be surprised if that makes a difference but its worth checking out.