# Rails 3: caches_action and root :to problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, memcached

So I use `caches_action :page` in my Public controller. In my routes.rb I point `root :to => "public#page"`
. The page action contains this line: `@pictures = Picture.paginate :page => params[:id] || 1`, so that normally the root path always shows the page action with the very first portion of pictures. My problem is that after I started to use cache, root sometimes displays the page action, but not with the id=1, but with another id (I guess it's just another cached 'page'), so that the pictures shown on root are not the newest ones.

How can I set it up so that root will always point to cached `:controller => public, :action => page, :id => 1`?

Comment: Is there a reason you _have_ to use action caching as opposed to fragment caching or something a bit more granular? Might be easier to carve out the dynamic elements that way. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action caching doesn't work with params (it ignores them).  You might try using JavaScript to extract the id from the URL and load the pictures via AJAX.

If you truly want to cache pages by the parameters then you will need to add custom logic to read/write the cache files.

EDIT: Caching doesn't consider *query string* parameters

UPDATE:

I think what you want to do is described here:
[Rails action caching with querystring parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988658/rails-action-caching-with-querystring-parameters)

Comment: How come then that caching seems to work properly for my other actions, i.e. /show/1 always display the first picture, and show/2 the second one and the routes never get 'mixed'?

Comment: Caching is based on URLs, but ignores the query string (I edited my answer to reflect that).  Since the `:id` param for the show action is part of the URL path your different requests to `show` are cached separately.

Comment: See updated answer for a link to caching with query string params

Comment: Thanks Wizard. I have put this in my code and am waiting to see if everything will work all right :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  I've found two good ways to solve it.  Option 1 will store a copy of all customized requests in your cache.  If your site has a lot of searches that won't be repeated, or your concerned about memory space, this isn't ideal.  Option 2 only caches pages without parameters.

1) As "Wizard of Ogz" linked to, you can use :cache_path to include the parameters in the cache key, so that pages with parameters are cached separately from the no-parameter request.

```
caches_action :page,
  :cache_path => proc {|c|
    {:tag => c.params}
  }
```

2) You can use :if to pass a proc and not cache the action at all if parameters are present.  This will keep custom searches out of your cache memory.

```
caches_action :page,
 :if => proc {
    params.blank?
  }
```

If it's a url other than your root, you can delete the controller and action params:

```
caches_action :page,
 :if => proc {
    updated_params = params.delete_if { |k,v| ['controller', 'action'].include?(k) }
    updated_params.blank?
  }
```

Here's the corresponding API info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer from the wizard of ogz - you might want to take a different approach here and instead of using action caching, set up a method in your picture class that returns you the newest pictures, cache the result of that method, and then update the cache when new pictures are loaded.  Then you could do something like

```
@pictures = params[:id] ? {(Picture.paginate :page => params[:id]) : (Rails.cache.fetch('Picture.new_ones'){Picture.paginate :page => 1})
```

Comment: I understand the logic, but unfortunately it wasnt working for me... and I dont really know why, but once I encountered the /page/2 as the root using this code as well :)