# how to cache a rails action with url parameters and be able to invalidate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm serving a users default picture from the url /:username/picture (much like facebook). The action takes several get parameters to specify the image dimension and style wanted. Here is an example:

/john/picture?d[]=50&d[]=50&s=square

This would return johns default picture at a size of 50px x 50px cropped as a square.

Hitting the whole rails stack for every picture request is obviously not efficient. I'd like to cache the image versions. This seems possible with something like the solution [to this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988658/rails-action-caching-with-querystring-parameters).

```
caches_action :my_action, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
```

However, I need to find a way to clear the cache for all the image versions when a user changes their default picture. Basically when john changes his default picture I wish I could clear with a regex similar to the below so that all of the default thumbnails will be regenerated with the new default picture:

clear cache /john/picture*

How would I accomplish this in rails?

Answer (score 1):

I could be misunderstanding your question, but I think you need a sweeper.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers

Comment: I've tried implementing through sweepers but could not come up with a working solution. If you can come up with a working solution I'll award you the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

alongside your `cache_index`, you can assign a class to `cache_sweeper` in your controller.

```
# assign the cache_sweeper
caches_action :my_action, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
cache_sweeper :picture_sweeper
```

then, alongside of your controllers, add in a new class

```
# class to help with sweeping up cached pictures
class PictureSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Picture # or whatever your class is called
  # ... be sure to read on how to setup a cache sweeper
  def after_update( record )
    # you should probably check if record.is_a? Picture or whatever your class is
    self.class::sweep( record )
  end
  # note there is also after_create, after_destroy, after_save

  def self.sweep( record )
    # the cache directory is in ActionController::Base.page_cache_directory
    # use the record to help reconstruct the path to your cached pictures
    # and delete whatever you need to
  end

  # note, i showed the sweeping split out from the after_update method in case you
  # wanted to sweep after several of the events... trying to be DRY...
end
```

[Cache Sweeping Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping.html)

Comment: Hi there. I understand sweepers. I'm not sure how to actually clear the cache in this case. I see the comments in there showing where it would be done... but how do you do it? Also, we use the file cache on our development machines and memcache in production. Finding and deleting the actual files on disk would only work for file cache. Is there a rails way to do it independent of the cache storage you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://github.com/pennymac/action_param_caching for a simpler version of this.