# Discover expiry time for a given cache key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, pagination, memcached

Using Rails caching with Memcached implementation, is there any way to discover what time a particular item is scheduled to expire (if it exists).

I'm trying to solve the same problem mentioned here, which wasn't resolved:
[Rails caching: Expiring multiple pages for one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665712/rails-caching-expiring-multiple-pages-for-one-action). Basically, caching when pagination is involved.

Comment: None of the memcached commands will return the expiration time of a given key. If you could get the expiration time for a key how would you use it?

Comment: @mikewied For the scenario I mentioned here - ensuring `example.com?q=foo` and `example.com?q=foo&page=2` expire at the same time, even though they're cached as separate items. I think I've figured out how to do it without this functionality, which I'll explain in the linked question, but the functionality would make the solution a bit less convoluted.

Comment: I just realized that you can do stats key in order to get information about a key.